# Spritekit - Using gestures to draw multiple lines with multiple fingers simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

Using the below code, I can draw a line using the pan gesture using 1 finger. However what I am attempting to do is for 1 finger to draw 1 line and another finger to draw the second simultaneously. I've read somewhere about using a dictionary to store the touches but don't know how to write it in code. Can any one help?

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizerPan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePanFrom:)];
    [[self view] addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizerPan];

}

- (void)handlePanFrom:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
        touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];

        pathToDraw = CGPathCreateMutable();
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
        lineNode = [[SKShapeNode alloc] init];
        lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
        lineNode.name = lineNodeCategoryName;
        [_gameLineNode addChild:lineNode];

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint touchLocation = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
        touchLocation = [self convertPointFromView:touchLocation];

        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathToDraw, NULL, touchLocation.x, touchLocation.y);
        lineNode.path = pathToDraw;
        lineNode.name = lineNodeCategoryName;
        lineNode.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeChainFromPath:pathToDraw];
        lineNode.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor blackColor];
        lineNode.glowWidth = 3.0;

    } else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        CGPathRelease(pathToDraw);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drawing multiple lines simultaneously is fairly straightforward. The key is to track each touch event independently. One way to do that is to maintain a dictionary that uses the touch event as the key and the shape node (used to draw the line) as the value.

```
@implementation GameScene {
    NSMutableDictionary *lines;
}

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;
    // Create a mutable dictionary
    lines = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:10];
}

// Add each line node to the dictionary with the touch event as the key
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        // Create a mutable path
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path moveToPoint:location];
        // Create a shape node using the path
        SKShapeNode *lineNode = [SKShapeNode shapeNodeWithPath:path.CGPath];
        lineNode.strokeColor = [SKColor blackColor];
        [self addChild:lineNode];
        // Use touch pointer as the dictionary key. Since the dictionary key must conform to
        // NSCopying, box the touch pointer in an NSValue
        NSValue *key = [NSValue valueWithPointer:(void *)touch];
        [lines setObject:lineNode forKey:key];
    }
}

// Update the lines as needed
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        // Retrieve the shape node that corresponds to touch
        NSValue *key = [NSValue valueWithPointer:(void *)touch];
        SKShapeNode *lineNode = [lines objectForKey:key];
        if (lineNode != NULL) {
            // Create and initialize a mutable path with the lineNode's current path
            UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:lineNode.path];
            // Add a line to the current touch point
            [path addLineToPoint:location];
            // Update lineNode
            lineNode.path = path.CGPath;
        }
    }
}

// Remove the line nodes from the dictionary when the touch ends
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        NSValue *key = [NSValue valueWithPointer:(void *)touch];
        [lines removeObjectForKey:key];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Dude, this is awesome. Works a charm. Many thanks. The multiple line drawings allows me to create so many additional levels.

Comment: And i suppose, the same technique can be used when using gestures for anyone else who is doing something similar.

Comment: I try to avoid using gesture recognizers in SK because they need to be manually removed when you transition to another scene. The above, I believe, is a more SpriteKit-friendly approach.

Comment: Hi, quick question. You helped me with this a while back and need some more guidance if you can help. We used a dictionary to allow draw multiple lines. I have not included the touches end code to remove the lines but I want to remove the lines one by one via SKButton. Can you show me the method that I can use to remove the lines one by one? i.e draw two lines simultaneously, release and draw the next line. Click remove icon, removes the single line first. Click again and removes the first two lines. Thanks.

Comment: @user3482617 I suggest you add the lines (i.e., shape nodes) to an array as they are created and then retrieve the appropriate lines from the array when the button is tapped. You can then remove the line from the scene and from the array.

Comment: Really sorry, I just cant get it to work. Tried to add a SKshapenode to a array but says its incompatible. Could you give me a example please?

Comment: @user3482617 First, define the array with `var array:[SKShapeNode] = []`, then add a node to the array with `array.append(lineNode)`, and remove the node with `array[index].removeFromParent`. You can remove the last line with `if let line = array.last { line.removeFromParent}` or the first with `if let line = array.first {line.removeFromParent}`

Comment: in objective C? :)

Comment: @user3482617 define the array with `NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];` add node(s) to the array with ` [array addObject:lineNode];` and remove nodes from the scene with `[((SKShapeNode *)[array objectAtIndex:index]) removeFromParent];`

Comment: thanks, I think I know whats happening, as you add the Skshapenodes to the array, it is not adding more into the array, instead just replacing it the only one node. Hence why when I call the removeFromParent code, only the last one gets removed. I did a NSLog (count) of the nodes in the array and its always 1. Any idea?